# Accordion code return false causes an unexpected page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have [this FAQ page](http://codeandcode.co/demo/code&co-Seo/html/V2/faq.html) and have the following code for the accordion to work:

```
$('.indi-faq  a').on('çlick' , function(e){
    if ($(this).parent().hasClass('open')) {
        $(this).siblings('p').slideDown(500, function(){
            $(this).parent().addClass('open');
        });
    } else {
        $(this).siblings('p').slideUp(500, function(){
            $(this).parent().removeClass('open');
        });
    }
    return false;
});
```

The `return false` does not work and the page refreshes, why is the `return false` is not working?

P.S. The code is in `scroll.js` file

Comment: Did you notice this character `ç` in yuor `click` event string ? Your code is `....on('çlick' ,...` instead of `....on('click' ,...`

Comment: There is an "çlick" ç character....

Comment: lol I was cleaning my screen thinking that `ç` had some dirt on it.. :D

Comment: xaxaxaxaxa :) That's fine ;) :) xaxaxa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to replace the `ç` character with `c` in your `click` event string.

Your code should looks like this:

```
$('.indi-faq  a').on('click' , function(e){
    if ($(this).parent().hasClass('open')) {
        $(this).siblings('p').slideDown(500, function(){
            $(this).parent().addClass('open');
        });
    } else {
        $(this).siblings('p').slideUp(500, function(){
            $(this).parent().removeClass('open');
        });
    }
    return false;
});
```

Just mention the first line of the code snippet.

Answer (score 1):

Other than typo in click event, you can narrow down your code using `toggleClass` and `slideToggle()`

```
$('.indi-faq  a').on('click' , function(e){
  var $this = $(this);
  $this.siblings('p').slideToggle(500, function(){
      $this.parent().addClass('open');
  });
  return false;
});
```